# MS Project - Link multiple columns to the Resource Sheet

Tags: ms-project

I have (somehow) managed to create one column which successfully links to the Resource Sheet.  When using the drop down, it brings up all of the names in the resource sheet, and allows you to choose multiple names.  The column is then populated with all of the names selected.  I have also renamed this particular column for one of our roles (Approver)

I would like to add three more columns (for three additional roles: Action Owner, SME and Developer(s) ) which behave EXACTLY the same way, but cannot determine how to do this.

A simple "paste and copy" of the Approver column, does create another column, but, as expected, the values are exactly the same.  If you change a cell in the "Approver" column, the cell in the other column changes as well.  This is **not** what i need.

The four columns should all be able to choose values from the same resource sheet, allow multiple names per cell, and, most importantly be totally independent.

- For example

Approver:     John
Action Owner: Mary, Sue, Robert
SME:          Jason, Todd
Developers:   Crystal, Scott, Meredith

How (exactly - step by step), do I:

1. create each of these three new additional columns,
2. map them to the same Resource Sheet
3. have the capability of choosing multiple values for a cell
4. have all four columns work entirely independent of each other

Answer (score 1):

This is not how MS Project works.

A schedule has Tasks and Resources. One or more resources can be added to a task to create an ***assignment***. The assignment represents the work being done on the task by the resource(s). You can have have multiple resources working on a task but they will all be in one group (shown in a Task view as `Resource Names`).

You can use a numbered text field (e.g. `Text1`) to contain names of other resource categories (e.g. SMEs), but you'll need to type them in manually as they can't be tied to the schedule's Resources.

Comment: Can the numbered text field:  1) use a different list  2) can it be a drop down  3) can you choose multiple values?

Comment: Text fields can be customized with a drop-down list (Project tab, Custom Fields), but you can select only one value for each task. The values are not associated with the Resources. Different numbered text fields can have different lists.